# Is AMQP production ready?

Tags: .net, python, rabbitmq, amqp

I'd like to use AMQP to join two services one written in C# and other written in python.
I'm expecting quite large volume of messages per second.

- Is there any AMQP Broker that is production ready?
- Are the python & .net bindings good enough?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by production ready ? and what kind of work you are doing. Definitely none of the open source broker can be used for financial domain where losing one message means losing millions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seams that reddit said that rabbitMQ isn't ready as of may 2010.
http://blog.reddit.com/2010/05/reddits-may-2010-state-of-servers.html

On the other hand the article is about rabbitMQ < 2.0 which was crashing because of out of memory problems. According to release notes the version 2.0 and above has this bug fixed.

Answer (score 12):

Yes:  [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **robomq.io**. It is built on RabbitMQ core and has more extensions, e.g. messaging dashboard, realtime analytics, data-driven alerts, big data storage...

If you like high throughput, the record of **robomq.io** is 170 billion messages per day.

I'm not quite sure what you meant by Python & .NET binding. If you want cross-platform communication. robomq.io is your right choice. Not only cross-language, but also cross-prototol, among AMQP, MQTT and STOMP.

Check out elaborate docs (http://robomq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and sdk (https://github.com/robomq/robomq.io/tree/master/sdk) of **robomq.io**.